# How can I make a slide out nav without using z-index

Tags: javascript, css, react-router-v4

When using react router you can't make a slide out nav with z-index because there is a bug that makes the `<Link>` tags unclickable. Is there an alternative way of making the menu go underneath the div above it? Sorry I'm not the best at css, I've only seen people doing this with the z-index property and I can't find any tutorial that explains how to do it without setting the z-index.

here is a code example -

```
<style>
  .header {
    background: black;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .handle {
    background: red;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .menu-links {
    background: green;
    height: 285px;
    z-index: -1; /* this is what makes the <Link> tags unclickable */
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: all ease-in-out 300ms;
  }
</style>
<header className="header">
  [...]
</header>
<nav>
  <div className="handle" onClick={this.navToggle}>
    <span>Menu</span>
  <div>
  <ul className="menu-links" style={{left: this.state.toggle ? "-285px" : "0px"}}>
    <li><Link to="/home">Home</Link></li>
    <li><Link to="/products">Products</Link></li>
    <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
    <li><Link to="/contact">Contact</Link></li>
  <ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with the `react router`. But, The `z-index` property specifies the stack order of an element. An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order. So, if you create the menu at the end of the document (after all elements) and give it `fixed` or `absolute` position style, then you do not need to use the `z-index`.

Comment: Thank you guys for helping unfortunately I couldn't get it to work so I think I'm going go with a nav that slides out from the side.

Comment: @RyanSam can you show some code or screenshot of code..?

Comment: @Bhuwan I updated it for you, but I didn't think this was necessary because it's not a code problem, it's a `react-router-dom` bug. My reason for the question is to list alternatives to using z-index. Currently I have avoided the problem by instead going with a nav that slides out from the side of the window.

Answer (score 0):

You could use absolute positioning to accomplish this. An absolutely positioned element will automatically sit on top of its relative parent